# Continuously differentiable if and only if $Df(x)$ is continuous in $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

This should be trivial, but I simply want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding this.

---

I'm talking about differentiation in multiple dimensions / total differentiation.

Via definition, $Df(x)$ is an element of $L(\mathbb{R}^p, \mathbb{R}^q)$ (so just a linear function).
We have proven in our lectures that a linear function is continuous if and only if it is continuous in $0$.

So if I want to know whether a function is continuously differentiable I simply need to calculate the Jacobi Matrix (or somehow else the derivative) and check if it is continuous in $0$?

---

Is this right or is there a trivial mistake I manage not to see?

Comment: Continous differentiability refers to the map $\mathrm Df:x\mapsto\mathrm Df(x)$, not to the map $\mathrm Df(x):\mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R^q$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks